# Syntastic error with haskell

Tags: haskell, vim, syntastic

```
Error detected while processing /home/kyle/.vim/ftplugin/haskell_doc.vim:
```

This is an error I recive when running vim. I am trying to get syntastic to work with haskell. Here is the .vimrc file

```
"use ghc functionality for haskell files
au Bufenter *.hs compiler ghc 

" switch on syntax highlighting
syntax on

" side numbers 
set nu

let g:ghc = "/usr/bin/ghc"

execute pathogen#infect()

let g:haddock_docdir = "/usr/share/doc/ghc6-doc/html/"
" enable filetype detection, plus loading of filetype plugins
filetype plugin on
let g:haddock_browser = "/usr/bin/firefox"
```

Comment: is there more that the error message or is just that one line?

Comment: Just that one line thats why i am so confused Also syntastic doesnt work at all none of the features are happening

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning out your `.vim/` directory so it only has these files:

```
.vim/
├── autoload/
│   └── pathogen.vim
│
├── bundle/
    ├── syntastic/
        ├── CONTRIBUTING.md
        ├── LICENCE
        ├── README.markdown
            ...other syntastic files...
```

That is, you only have `.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim` and the files in `.vim/bundle/syntastic/`.

It looks like you have something in `.vim/ftplugin` which is causing problems.

Syntastic works for me on Haskell files with only these two lines in my .vimrc:

```
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
```

Note: You need to have `ghc-mod` installed.

Comment: Syntastic features are still not working even with removing all the offending files. I believe they are not working because I dont have a syntax checker now. I confimed this with :syntasticInfo. Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you still getting an error message? Does syntastic work on other language files -- e.g. python / perl / c++ source files?

Comment: No more error msgs. I tested it with C and it is working fine.

Comment: Updated answer. Do you have `ghc-mod` installed? Try this sample command: `ghc-mod check some-haskell-file.hs`

Comment: Ah in my spree of deleting files i accidently deleted ghc-mod silly me. Thank you so much for your help. Everything is working fine now